# Genos VS Mosquito Girl Soundtrack

Tags: music, one-punch-man

So I was rewatching One Punch Man, and when Genos started fighting Mosquito Girl, I was really enjoying the music. Is it on the OST, or is anyone able to tell me where it is from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.
The name of the song is **"The Cyborg Fights"**, or it can be found under the name of **"Genos Fight Theme"**.

Here are some links where you can listen the song:

> [One Punch Man OST - The Cyborg Fight (Genos' Theme)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJ0EERmmlB0) on YouTube

It is present in the **official soundtrack of the anime** (track #5 [on the OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/55383)).